# Unable to use Noble on node => Error: EAFNOSUPPORT, Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm on ubuntu terminal on windows, I tried to install @abandonware/noble, a BLE module for node.js, the installation succeed but when I try to launch my program, the program stop at my first line : `const noble = require('@abandonware/noble');`
I have this error :

```
/mnt/c/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Documents/Cours ESIR/Cours ESIR2/Projet IoT/groupe-1bis-homedeck-christophe-maxime-paul/testNoble/node_modules/@abandonware/noble/lib/hci-socket/hci.js:74
  this._socket = new BluetoothHciSocket();
                 ^

Error: EAFNOSUPPORT, Address family not supported by protocol
    at new Hci (/mnt/c/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Documents/Cours ESIR/Cours ESIR2/Projet IoT/groupe-1bis-homedeck-christophe-maxime-paul/testNoble/node_modules/@abandonware/noble/lib/hci-socket/hci.js:74:18)
    at new NobleBindings (/mnt/c/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Documents/Cours ESIR/Cours ESIR2/Projet IoT/groupe-1bis-homedeck-christophe-maxime-paul/testNoble/node_modules/@abandonware/noble/lib/hci-socket/bindings.js:25:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Documents/Cours ESIR/Cours ESIR2/Projet IoT/groupe-1bis-homedeck-christophe-maxime-paul/testNoble/node_modules/@abandonware/noble/lib/hci-socket/bindings.js:546:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at module.exports (/mnt/c/Users/maxim/OneDrive/Documents/Cours ESIR/Cours ESIR2/Projet IoT/groupe-1bis-homedeck-christophe-maxime-paul/testNoble/node_modules/@abandonware/noble/lib/resolve-bindings.js:13:12) {
  errno: 97,
  code: 'EAFNOSUPPORT',
  syscall: 'socket'
}
```

```
node -v 
v12.20.0
npm -v
6.14.8
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall after, but nothing change. I was previously in the latest version of Node.js and downgrade it but nothing change too.
I don't know how to solve it, if you have an idea, I will gladly hear it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your code please -  I would like to see how you import the module, the events you are listening to, and how you instantiate the BlootoothHciSocket

Comment: What exactly did you install and how? Did you install the [dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abandonware/noble#windows) according to the readme? What driver are you using?

Comment: I first tried the quick example code on noble githup : https://github.com/abandonware/noble but didn't worked and currently my code is just '''const noble = require('@abandonware/noble');
console.log("hello Noble");''' 
I didn't instantiate the BlootoothHciSocket myself.
For the installation, yes I followed the readme with the prerequisites of Linux

Comment: @Maxime, did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm getting the same error, using WSL2 on Windows 11, even though the same code and dependencies work fine in native Ubuntu, and even on Windows (with corresponding dependencies)